# AG-Grid in play application

Tags: ag-grid

I was trying to use ag-grid in my playframework application.
As soon as the data is plotted in the table, the height of the grid starts increasing automatically.It keeps on increasing in every few seconds.

The div with class "ag-floating-bottom " is increasing in height.

The grid is working fine when run separately.

Can anyone suggest as to why is this happening.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occurring for me for class="ag-fresh" not on other styles.